# org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`angelique`' given input columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have a table created by using a data frame and I try to launch a query as below shown :

```
 val sc = SparkSession.builder()
                            .master("local")
                            .appName("Lea")
                            .getOrCreate()
   // example login = angelique
   var login:String = (givenName+"."+sn).replaceAll(" ", "")

   sc.sql("SELECT login FROM global_temp.users where login="+login).show
```

Output error :

```
17/04/26 10:11:01 INFO SparkSqlParser: Parsing command: users
17/04/26 10:11:01 INFO SparkSqlParser: Parsing command: SELECT login FROM global_temp.users where login=angelique
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`angelique`' given input columns: [idExterne, login, password, uid]; line 1 pos 48;
'Project ['login]
+- 'Filter (login#60 = 'angelique)
   +- SubqueryAlias users, `global_temp`.`users`
      +- Project [_1#50 AS idExterne#59, _2#51 AS login#60, _3#52 AS password#61, _4#53 AS uid#62]
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code

```
sc.sql(s"SELECT login FROM global_temp.users where login='$login'").show
```

it will work

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, a dot is not permitted in a column name in Spark 2.0.1.  I'm not sure it is permitted in a DF name. Maybe you can try to omit or replace the dot in the DF name?

Answer (score 0):

try this

sc.sql(s"SELECT login FROM global_temp.users where login==='$login'").show

Comment: Why would this help in anyway? String concatenation usually works fine

Comment: Yes thats right concatenation works fine as u said. Above  procedure  might be a two step process to achive the result ,first we need to pass the concated value and then we need to pass it .